# wget - Double downloads with query strings in URLs

Tags: jquery, double, download, special-characters, wget

I have to use wget to download, with the recursive option (`-r`), all the files in a web page.

This page contains N direct links to the N files (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/page/File_n.abc), but also contains other N "undirect" links (query strings) to theese files (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/page/File_n.abc?cd=at).

How can I avoid to download theese files (identical to the first ones).

I tried the option `-R *cd*` but wget deletes the files **after** the download.
I noticed that, using the option `-R *xyz*`, the program doesn't download any file containing "xyz", only if "xyz" is in the part of the link before the "`?`" symbol.
Otherwise the program downloads the file and **than** deletes it.

The *wget* ***manual*** says: "Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (‘?’) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings."

Any idea?

Comment: I think this question belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I'll post the question on that site. Thank you